# Is there a way to install chrome web store apps without signing in?

Tags: google-chrome

I find it slightly disconcerting that I had to create a fake gmail account just to install an app. Is there any way around this?

***edit***

The app is [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm). I tried going to the web store page for AdBlock, which is an extension and it didn't prompt me to sign in, so maybe this is just for apps?

Comment: I'm confused. Can you download Mac / iTunes apps without signing in? No.. Same applies for Google. If you wanted this app without creating an account, maybe look on the internet for a direct mirror?

Comment: "Look, they do it too!" is hardly a defense of this behaviour from Google. If it's a local app that has nothing to do with a Google account, it *shouldn't* be tied to an account. Same goes for iTunes.

Comment: ahh well, that's life - huh? I believe though, they do it because if there is an update etc.. then it is a lot easier for you to update to the latest version. Also, if something happens to your PC, it is much more easier to download your apps again. I don't like downloading apps that are not from the app store - Is that just me?

Comment: Extensions have automatically updated for years now, so that's likely not the case. Transferring your apps to other installs is a good feature, but it shouldn't be a forced feature IMO.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with chromium and also don't see any option to install apps without google account. Probably time to switch back to firefox again.

Answer (score 8):

For Postman specifically, you can download a zip of the source code from: https://github.com/a85/POSTMan-Chrome-Extension

Once you have downloaded and uncompressed the files:

- Go to Chrome's menu and select **Tools**, then **Extensions**.
- Click **Developer Mode** on the Extensions page.
- Click **Load unpacked extension...**
- In the pop up file dialog, select the **chrome** folder from the
  files you downloaded.